# Javascript - Images that I have inserted into localstorage come out as broken image files after a refresh. Blob:null URL overwritten?

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage, blob

I have been trying to program a site where you can upload images to a database. However, whenever I upload a new image and refresh the page, the image turns into undefined broken image link. I have tried virtually everything to fix it from simplifying the code to turning it to base64, but nothing seems to work on my end.

It seems the problem is that the blob:null address of the image is overwritten with a new address whenever the page is refreshes, I don't know what part of the code has to be changed to stop this and how.

Here is the main code that adds images and saves and loads them to localstorage

```
function addImage() {
    const imageGallery = document.getElementById('imageGallery');
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');

    if (deleteMode) {
        alert('Turn off Delete Mode before adding new images.');
        return;
    }

    const files = fileInput.files;

    if (files.length > 0) {
        for (const file of files) {
            const newImageDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newImageDiv.className = 'gallery responsive';
            var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            const newImageLink = document.createElement('a');
            newImageLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
            newImageLink.setAttribute('href', objectUrl);

            const newImage = document.createElement('img');
            newImage.setAttribute('src', objectUrl);
            newImage.setAttribute('alt', 'Image description');
            newImage.setAttribute('width', '25%');
            newImage.setAttribute('height', '25%');

            const newDesc = document.createElement('div');
            newDesc.className = 'desc';
            newDesc.innerHTML = 'Add a description of the image here';

            const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
            checkbox.className = 'imageCheckbox';

            newImageLink.appendChild(newImage);
            newImageDiv.appendChild(newImageLink);
            newImageDiv.appendChild(newDesc);
            newImageDiv.appendChild(checkbox);

            imageGallery.appendChild(newImageDiv);
        }

        saveImagesToLocalStorage();
    }
}

  function saveImagesToLocalStorage() {
    const imageGallery = document.getElementById('imageGallery');
    const imagesData = [];

    const images = imageGallery.getElementsByClassName('gallery responsive');
    for (const image of images) {
        const imgLink = image.querySelector('a');
        const imgDesc = image.querySelector('.desc');

        if (imgLink && imgDesc) {
            imagesData.push({
                src: imgLink.getAttribute('href'),
                alt: imgDesc.innerText
            });
        }
    }

    localStorage.setItem('galleryImages', JSON.stringify(imagesData));
}


function loadImagesFromLocalStorage() {
    const imageGallery = document.getElementById('imageGallery');

    if (imageGallery) {
        const imagesData = localStorage.getItem('galleryImages');

        if (imagesData) {
            const images = JSON.parse(imagesData);

            for (const imageInfo of images) {
                const newImageDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newImageDiv.className = 'gallery responsive';

                const newImageLink = document.createElement('a');
                newImageLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                newImageLink.setAttribute('href', imageInfo.src);

                const newImage = document.createElement('img');
                newImage.setAttribute('src', imageInfo.src);
                newImage.setAttribute('alt', imageInfo.alt);
                newImage.setAttribute('width', '600');
                newImage.setAttribute('height', '400');

                const newDesc = document.createElement('div');
                newDesc.className = 'desc';
                newDesc.innerHTML = imageInfo.desc;

                newImageLink.appendChild(newImage);
                newImageDiv.appendChild(newImageLink);
                newImageDiv.appendChild(newDesc);

                imageGallery.appendChild(newImageDiv);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML that references the javascript code

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display:none;" accept="image/*" onchange="addImage()">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click()">Select a file</button>

<div id="imageGallery" class="clearfix">
```

[Here is what the broken image gallery looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lskG.png)

[This is what it looks like after I tried to simplify the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V8jt.png)

I tried to add this snippet of code before `const images = JSON.parse(imagesData);`

```
images.push(bookmark);
localStorage.setItem("imagesData", JSON.stringify(imagesData));
```

But it then proceeded to not save any images. Same thing happened with various other alterations to the code.

Like I said, I tried to add base64 code to it, but it had no effect on the images.

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
            
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            
                return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            }
```

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to include saveImagestoLocalStorage section, which looks like this, however it seems to not be part of the problem, but should help provide context to the problem as a whole.

'''

```
function addImage() {
                const imageGallery = document.getElementById('imageGallery');
                const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    
                if (deleteMode) {
                    alert('Turn off Delete Mode before adding new images.');
                    return;
                }
    
                saveImagesToLocalStorage();
            }
    
            function saveImagesToLocalStorage() {
                const imageGallery = document.getElementById('imageGallery');
                ImagesData = getBase64Image(imageGallery);
    
                const images = imageGallery.getElementsByClassName('gallery responsive');
                for (const image of images) {
                    const imgLink = image.querySelector('a');
                    const imgDesc = image.querySelector('.desc');
    
                    if (imgLink && imgDesc) {
                        ImagesData.push({
                            src: imgLink.getAttribute('href'),
                            alt: imgDesc.innerText
                        });
                    }
                }
    
                localStorage.setItem('galleryImages', JSON.stringify(ImagesData));
            }

            function getBase64Image(img) {
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = img.width;
                canvas.height = img.height;
            
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            
                return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            }
    
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                loadImagesFromLocalStorage();
            });
```

'''

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static: _"The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created."_ - so this means, such BLOB URLs will never survive a reload, or going to a different page and then coming back.

Comment: _"I tried to add base64 code to it, but it had no effect on the images"_ - we can't tell _how_ you tried to integrate this into the process. You _should_ perhaps be storing those Data URIs directly; right now, since you are _removing_ the `data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,` prefix, I am guessing you are _still_ creating BLOB URLs from this afterwards? Then you have the same problem again.

Comment: The base64 code is part of the saveImagesToLocalStorage code, which I've now included in the original post.

Comment: `ImagesData = getBase64Image(imageGallery);` - this function expects a single image element as parameter; your `const imageGallery = document.getElementById('imageGallery');` however is a `div` element.

Comment: You are saving the a[href] value and then using it in the img[src]. This certainly is the reason why it does not work.

Comment: I replaced the "href" mentions with "src". But nothing has changed. But thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: In it's current state, it is too hard to help. There are functions everywhere in your question, some are shown twice, sometimes with different content... Please make things clear and easy for us to dive in the code and help you. Also, as @CBroe pointed out, you cannot use blob URLs so only include code without it (base64) that you tried.